# Unity Panel Interaction Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, uiscrollview, panel

I have two panels in unity 2d directly overlapping each other and they use scroll panels so I can scroll down. I have it set so when one is accessed, the other is pulled up, but when they swap the other panel is grey and I cannot interact with it, but when I attempt to scroll the other panel scrolls instead, even though it is hidden and turned off.

Comment: Could you show your code? Probably in particular the one for swapping panels?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a bug in the code. It's possible, that when the user presses the scroll button in the first panel, and then releases the button, the second panel's scroll button thinks, it's already been pressed by the user, when in fact it isn't.

Set it up in such a way, that when you release the button on a scrollbar (the first scroll bar), it resets the click on the scrollbars connected to it (a second scroll bar).